# Can I use existing HTML and CSS code in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I've created a restaurant webpage from scratch (my first full webpage). I want to get into freelance work, but I've heard that a lot of people use WordPress and it's plugins to create websites fast. I'm not really a fan of template editing, but can I use my existing HTML and CSS, upload it to WordPress and edit it there, and utilize WordPress plugins? I really want to add stuff like online ordering, RSVP systems, or mini stores on these sites.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions here should be about a specific, practical programming-related problem that has fact-based answers. Other than saying "yes, kind of" to answer the title, the rest of your question doesn't appear to have a specific problem. I you are looking for information about *how* to do this, that also is too vague and broad to be on topic.

Comment: FYI there are lots of tutorials and guides online that might help if you Google your question. If you run into any *specific* problems or have a specific coding-related question, come back with the details and we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use your own HTML, CSS or JavaScript to create a theme and start from there. It might take you longer but you can do it.

Wordpress allows you to create a "Child Theme". With this, you are able to have your own stlying (css) or custom JavaScript. The advantage of doing this is when the theme publisher (assuming you are not the original creator of the theme) updates the theme, all your custom styles and JavaScript will remain intact. That is a good way of going around it.

If you want a quick solution, most themes come with a "Customize" section where you are able to paste your own styling. All the best!

A helpful link on creating child themes is https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 2):

No Problem, you would be able to make custom templates with your existing HTML/CSS/PHP. While having the ability to take advantage of plugins. Using an open source platform like WordPress will give the administrative rights to the restaurant owner, and most likely prevent the requirement for maintaining the website.